# AuthorizedKeysFile line commented out but still seems to work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm setting up a server on Linode and following their [Securing Your Server](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server) guide.

They recommend setting up ssh key pair authentication. I have already uploaded my public key to server and the key pair authentication seems to work fine, but how does it work if the following line is commented out in `sshd_config`:

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is the default location.  You can use `AuthorizedKeysFile` to change to a different location, but if you don't specify it, then it will look in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

From the man page (e.g., https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5):

> AuthorizedKeysFile
>
> ```
>    Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used
>    for user authentication.  The format is described in the AUTHO-
>    RIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section of sshd(8).  AuthorizedKeysFile
>    may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during
>    connection setup.  The following tokens are defined: %% is
>    replaced by a literal '%', %h is replaced by the home directory
>    of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the user-
>    name of that user.  After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken
>    to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's home direc-
>    tory.  Multiple files may be listed, separated by whitespace.
>    The default is ``.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2''.
> ```

Comment: And further, if you want the key not to work, delete the file, the relevant line, or comment it out.

Comment: you can also set it to "none" .